# ESP32 crashes when starting a 3 phase induction motor through a star delta starter

Tags: arduino, esp32, esp8266, induction-motor, emi-filtering

**Circuit Details:**
An esp32 driving 2 relays(5V SPDT HL JQC-3FC(T73)DC5V) via a darlington array(ULN2803A). The relays are connected to the start, stop buttons on a star-delta motor starter. The motor is a 3 phase 440V(LL) induction motor rated at 7HP. The esp32 is powered by a 5V (20W) meanwell power supply connected to one of the phases(R) and neutral line(N).

**Problem:**

The esp32 crashes(keeps printing garbage over serial) when the motor is turned off. It happens only when the motor is connected.

**Things I've tried:**

1. A large cap on the 5V input line from the meanwell power supply.
2. A 6V bidirectional TVS diode across the 5V input.
3. Changed the power supply twice.

Is there something that I'm missing. I'm out of options on what to try next.

Edit:
[image: Schematic]

Comment: You are missing relays type, coil voltage,  "crashing" details.  Does the relays have flyback diodes? Better to draw full schematic.

Comment: Schematics, PCB layout and wiring details are a must to even start analyzing what you should try next.

Comment: Relays have stray capacitance from the contacts to the coil. Enough of a transient when the starter circuit switched couples through the relay and tries to find a way back to earth. Your esp32 is the meat in the sandwich.  How is your circuit earthed? The physical details are important.

Comment: @user263983 I've already mentioned the relay type. It's a 5V SPDT Sugar Cube Relay(HL JQC-3FC(T73)DC5V).  Both the relays are driven by a darlington array that has flybackdiodes built-in. By "crashing" I mean the esp keeps printing out garbage over the serial and recovers only when it's reset. I'll edit my question to include a schematic.

Comment: @Justme I've updated my question with the schematic.